# Use bastions config file for server configuration

Tags: ssh, bastion

I'm in the process of setting up a jump server/bastion host for several of our developers and was wondering if it is possible to use the `config` file on the **bastion** for final server resolution.

E.g. we have

- developer
- bastion
- client

Currently, I have the following in the developer `.ssh/config`

```
Host bastion
  HostName bastion-address.com
  User developer

Host client
  User client-user
  HostName client-ip
  ProxyJump bastion
```

However, what would be great is if I could set the client user & ip on the bastion. That way, the developer doesn't need to know the details, just the `Host` name to connect.

So would imagine something like the following on the developer laptops:

```
Host bastion
  HostName bastion-address.com
  User developer

Host client-server
  HostName client-name
  ProxyJump bastion
```

And then this on the Bastion:

```
Host client-name
  User client-user
  HostName client-ip
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The "problem" is that "ProxyJump"  works by TCP forwarding traffic to `client` over the connection to the bastion server. It doesn't run a ssh (or any other helper command ) on the bastion, so it won't use/read configuration files there either.

Comment: That's kind of what I expected, I didn't know if I could use `ProxyCommand` instead to utilise the bastion host?

Answer (score 0):

Use DNS.

Create AAAA records for bastion.example.net, client.example.net and so on with the IPs in question.

Delete IP addresses in ssh_config.